# Removing an item from a stack, whilst iterating over it, in android

Tags: java, android, stack

Usually, in java, to delete an item from a stack (or set) I would do something along the lines of:

```
Stack<Particle> particles = new Stack<Particle>();
int i = 0, ;
while(i < particles.size()) {
    if(particles.elementAt(i).isAlive()) {
        i ++;
    } else {
        particles.remove(i);
    }
}
```

I've searched the android docs and googled quite a few times in an attempt to achieve the same results, but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: The android implementation follows Java's, with `Stack` extending `Vector` (which implements `elementAt()` and `remove()`).  [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Vector.html#remove%28int%29).  Presumably it should work exactly the same.  In fact, even on android `Stack` is in the `java.util` package, which makes me even more confident that the behavior is the same.

Comment: 'nothing seems to work' does not really state what the problem is. Compile error? runtime error? silently not working?

Comment: as for the first comment, i tried doing it the exact same, but element at doesn't exist. the method can't be found. i thought it odd because it was still in java.util but even so, the method cannot be found.
as for the second comment, i've gotten errors ranging from the aforementioned compile errors to the app unfortunately stopping. using an iterator object seemed to work fairly well, but it didn't allow me to edit elements without throwing an exception when i tried to get the next element, despite checking for another element first, and only executing if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looping using an `Iterator`, since per Oracle `Iterator.remove()` is the only safe way 
to remove an item from a `Collection` (including a `Stack`) during iteration.

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html

> Note that Iterator.remove is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified in any other way while the iteration is in progress.

So something like the following should work:

```
Stack<Particle> particles = new Stack<Particle>();
... // Add a bunch of particles
Iterator<Particle> iter = particles.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Particle p = iter.next();
    if (!p.isAlive()) {                
        iter.remove();            
    }
}
```

I've used this approach in a real Android app ([OneBusAway Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joulespersecond.seattlebusbot) - see code [here](https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android/blob/35fbc9549dc5bff8ff1c0c0bc71274b4d6d13c20/src/com/joulespersecond/seattlebusbot/RegionsFragment.java#L124)), and it worked for me.  Note that in the code for this app I also included a try/catch block in case the platform throws an exception, and in this case just iterate through a copy of the collection and then remove the item from the original collection.

For you, this would look like:

```
try {
   ... // above code using iterator.remove
} catch(UnsupportedOperationException e) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Problem removing from stack using iterator: " + e);
    // The platform apparently didn't like the efficient way to do this, so we'll just 
    // loop through a copy and remove what we don't want from the original
    ArrayList<Particle> copy = new ArrayList<Particle>(particles);
    for (Particle p : copy) {
        if (!p.isAlive()) {                
            particles.remove(p);                
        }
    }
}
```

This way you get the more efficient approach if the platform supports it, and if not you still have a backup.

Comment: this is what i tried after i found my stack method didn't work. but it kept trying to get another item when it had none despite we asking if it had next before getting next. either way i didn't user iterator.remove(); so i will certainly try this! i have to go to school but i will be back to see if this worked!

Comment: Thanks, let me know how it goes!  I also just added a reference to where I've used this in a real app, along with some fallback code if the more efficient version doesn't work.

Comment: i quite like the copying idea! one question about it though; When you create the copy, are the objects in the list copied, or are they just referenced with a different alias. ie, could i modify one in the copy and have the regular one and the copy be affectd?

Comment: Glad it worked!  For the copying - the references to the objects are copied from the first collection into a new collection.  So if you modified the object in one collection (e.g., p.setAlive(true)),  the same object in the second collection would also be modified (since both collections just contain a list of references pointing to the same objects).

Answer (score -2):

Have you ever try this:

```
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
stack.push("S");
stack.push("d");
for (String s : stack){
     stack.pop();
}
```

Comment: this won't work for two reasons, stacks apparently do not implement Iterable and you can't edit a stack while iterating over it. hence why i used a while in the first place.

Comment: @MarcusGosselin `java.util.Stack<T>` implements `Iterable<T>`.

Comment: I tried it. the code will  loop from first item to last item. How ever, pop will remove the last item, so, it doesn't work as you want. If you want to remove an `item` in the middle of `stack`, why using `stack`. It makes no sense.

Comment: it makes perfect sense. if you have a stack of items that have a living status, im not waiting until all 5 on the top and dead to get rid of the fifth down on the stack. and as for it implementing iterable, i thought it did as well but it tells me it does not.